# I cant figure out whats wrong on my update code

Tags: php, html, sql, wamp

This is the code that im using to display the data.(registos.php)

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','');
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
}

mysqli_select_db($con,'databaseteste');

$result =mysqli_query($con,("SELECT * FROM `formando2`"));
if (!$result) {
printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($con));
exit();
}

echo "<table class=mainmenu border='1' width=100% >
<p><caption><h1>Registos</h1></caption></p>
<tr>
<th>Primeiro Nome</th>
<th>Ultimo Nome</th>
<th>Numero C.C</th>
<th>Numero contribuinte</th>
<th>Email</th>
<th>Morada</th>
<th>Código postal</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr><form action=update.php method=post>";
echo "<td><input type=text name=pname value='".$row['PrimeiroNome']."'></td>";
echo "<td><input type=text name=sname value='".$row['UltimoNome']."'></td>";
echo "<td><input type=text name=bi value='".$row['NumeroBI']."'></td>";
echo "<td><input type=text name=contri value='".$row['NumeroContribuinte']."'></td>";
echo "<td><input type=text name=email value='".$row['Email']."'></td>";
echo "<td><input type=text name=morada value='".$row['Morada']."'></td>";
echo "<td><input type=text name=cpostal value='".$row['CodigoPostal']."'></td>";
echo "<td><input type=hidden name=id value='".$row['idformando2']."'></td>";
echo "<td><input type=submit></td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

This is the code that's giving me the problem i guess, in the update code.(update.php)

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','');
if (!$con){die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());}

mysqli_select_db($con,'databaseteste');

$update ="update `formando2` 
                set PrimeiroNome='$_POST[pname]',
                    UltimoNome='$_POST[sname]',
                    NumeroBI='$_POST[bi]',
                    NumeroContribuinte='$_POST[contri]',
                    Email='$_POST[email]',
                    Morada='$_POST[morada]',
                    CodigoPostal='$_POST[cpostal]' 
            where idformando2='$_POST[id]'";

if(mysqli_query($con,$update)){
    header("refresh:1; url=registos.php");}
else{
    printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($con));
}   
?>
```

When i submit it redirect's me to the update.php page then to the registos.php again, but the data still is the same.
[Registo Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GP43.png)

[Post update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSEgB.png)

Comment: Your script is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: You dont make any effort to check all these `$_POST` values actually exist

Comment: @AbdullaNilam Yes it does, see the hidden field at the end of the form

Comment: @RiggsFolly what do you mean ?

Comment: Your code just assumes all the $_POST values will be filled in `isset()`

Comment: @EduardoFernandes , I think you did not close `</form>` tag. use `echo "</form></tr>";` just before end of while loop in registos.php,

Comment: You aren't closing your `<form>` tag in the `while` loop as far as I can see. Since this loop can obviously render multiple forms to the page, you might have an issue with nested forms, or just invalid HTML, causing confusion when you post back. And as others have mentioned, your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks where someone could easily steal, delete, vandalise or otherwise mess with your data, and you are doing absolutely nothing to validate it or protect it.

Comment: Well thanks @ADyson,@Bhaskar for the help, i guess i dint observed the code whit my fullest atention cause i didnt expect the solution to be so simple.

Comment: Also want to thanks @JohnConde,@RiggsFolly for the Sql Injection warning and the validation on my post´s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't closing your form tag.

You need

```
echo "</form></tr>";
```

instead of

```
echo "</tr>";
```

in registos.php

Since this loop can obviously render multiple forms to the page, you might have an issue with nested forms, or just invalid HTML, causing confusion when you post back.

Answer (score -1):

I think you have not put name of the input box in single quotes or double quotes of all fields

it should be

echo "";